# Delphi 2007 and Indy 10 using https and SSL

Tags: delphi, indy

I've dropped a TIdHTTP and a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL, set the IOHandler of the IdHTTP to the SSL handler, set the mode of the TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to sllmClient. And then added the button click event below. The first time I get this error from WhichFailedToLoad.

[image]

Displayed, the second time I press the button it works. The ssl dll's are in the .exe diretory.

The service works fine from the browser and is in production. Why doesn't it work the first time?

```
procedure TForm32.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  output : TMemoryStream;
begin
    output:=TMemoryStream.Create;
//    IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(
  try
    IdHTTP1.get('https://localhost:444/Folder/service.svc',output);
    output.position := 0;
    memo1.lines.LoadFromStream(output);
  except
    on exception do
    ShowMessage(WhichFailedToLoad());
  end;
end;
```

tia

Comment: The first time I get this error from WhichFailedToLoad. displayed, the second time I press the button it works. Why doesn't it work the first time? Updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: I think it shows you which exported functions could not be found when loading the OpenSSL libraries. Check your OpenSSL libraries. If it works afterwards then probably your code doesn't use any of the missing exports so you can also ignore the exception in this case.

Comment: hmm, I put a flag in so the first time it does an extra get and gobbles up the exception it throws - I still got the message on the second get, then I put in a sleep(10) between the 2 gets and the message went away. Is there any other way to load the dll's without trying to do a connect?

Comment: Where did you put the SSL DLLs? In the same folder as the executable?

Comment: Yes. I checked they were the Delphi indy ones - I don't have the download here - that's something I'll have to check tomorrow. From looking around the web - it's because I'm using the wrong DLL's, so maybe the search path is wrong, or it's a version problem. Anything else you can suggest I should check? Thanks

Comment: Where did you put the DLLs? Are they in the same folder as the exe? How do you make sure the right ones are loaded. Which files are loaded? Check with Process Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be using a really old and outdated version of Indy 10 - most of the reported functions in that message box have an `_Indy` suffix on them.

Indy 9 and earlier, and early Indy 10 releases, require custom-built OpenSSL DLLs that add Indy-specific functions to access internal OpenSSL data that was not yet exposed in the public OpenSSL API.  Once that data was exposed in later API releases, Indy 10 was updated to no longer require the custom-built DLLs anymore.  It now uses the standardized OpenSSL DLLs as-is.

So you either need to track down the old custom-built Indy OpenSSL DLLs, or you need to upgrade to an up-to-date Indy 10 version.

Comment: I was afraid that was the problem, I shall upgrade. Thanks. I tried some older dll's but different problems.

Answer (score 3):

You should update to the [latest version of Indy](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/) and the [ssl dlls's](http://blog.digivendo.com/2012/05/openssl-0-9-8x-1-0-0j-1-0-1c/), this should get rid of the exception altogether.